# Analyzing Qualcomm Hexagon coredump file

Tags: coredump, qualcomm

Which tools exist for analysis of Qualcomm DSP Hexagon crash postmortem files (CODERAM.BIN, DATARAM.BIN) ?
TRACE32 do not support Data.LOAD.CORE command for Hexagon (according to Lauterbach support).
I have relevant ELF file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Crashman Tool from
<platform_BSP_folder>/adsp_proc/crashman/

Comment: Where I can find Crashman Tool ?
The only reference to the tool I have found is in below gillab. Is it relevant ?
https://gitlab.mingwork.com/hanguoliang

Comment: Crashman Tool is distributed inside Qualcomm BSP for the particular platform. BSP repositories are located at Qualcomm ChipCode [https://chipcode.qti.qualcomm.com] If you work with the Qualcomm platform you must have already downloaded the corresponding BSP.